# Python Popen downloads only one file

Tags: python, asynchronous, process, popen

I have a flickapi.py file which can be called like ./flickrapi author photos  and it downloads 20 photos of

If I call it directly or use

```
x = popen(['./flickrapi', 'author', 'photos', name])
x.wait()
x.communicate()
```

everything is ok

But if I use only

```
popen(['./flickrapi', 'author', 'photos', name])
```

Only one photo is downloaded ...

All I need is to call the script asynchroniously to download the photos, any tips for me?

Comment: What is the real problem? Why can't be called as described at first?

Comment: The problem is, that I need to call the process Asynchroniously, so If the "caller" will end the child will continue ... And I dont want to wait to end download ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because of the buffer size. `communicate()` will put data into memory so that program won't stuck. And, of course, all of photos will be downloaded. Here is details for `wait` and `communicate` functions.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: So you mean, the problem is in output? Why would it stuck if all photos are downloaded using urllib to concrete file?

Comment: @KOLEGA I don't know what did flickrapi do. But I guess if you don't call wait and comminucate, it will download a limited buffer size of file(I remember limitation is 64KB) and then stop.

Comment: calling single line popen (['./flickrapi.py', 'asda' 'ASD' 'ASD']) makes the problem ... When I am NOT using the wait() and communicate() so its not their problem ...